# Verify Legendre Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, legendre-polynomials

Knowing $P_1(x) = x$ and

$Q_1(x) = \frac{1}{2}xlog\frac{1+x}{1-x} - 1 $

I need to verify they satisfy the Legendre equation:

$(1-x^2)y'' - 2xy' + n(n+1)y = 0$

so far I've gotten the derivatives of $P_1(x) = x$, $P'_1(x) = 1$, $P''_1(x) = 0$

and $Q_1(x) = \frac{1}{2}xlog\frac{1+x}{1-x} - 1 $, $Q'_1(x) = \frac{x}{1-x^2}\frac{1}{2}xlog\frac{1+x}{1-x}$, $Q''_1(x) = \frac{2}{(x^2 - 1)^2} $

so I sub in $y'' = P''_1(x)$ and $y' = P'_1(x)$ and $y = P_1(x)$ but I don't get 0 because of the $n(n+1)y$ term...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: A minus sign is missing in $Q'_1(x)$

Comment: Note that n is equal to the index of $P_n$ or $Q_n$. Hence in your case n equals 1.

Answer (score 1):

Need some LaTeX practice so here goes :-)

$(1-x^2)P_1^{''}-2xP_1^{'} + 2P_1 = 0-2x+2x=0$

\begin{cases}
Q_1^{'} = \frac{1}{2}log\frac{1+x}{1-x} + \frac{x}{2}(\frac{1}{1+x} + \frac{1}{1-x}) = \frac{1}{2}log\frac{1+x}{1-x} + \frac{x}{1-x^2}
\\ Q_1^{''} = \frac{1}{1-x^2} + \frac{1-x^2 -x\cdot-2x}{(1-x^2)^2} = \frac{1}{1-x^2} + \frac{1+x^2}{(1-x^2)^2} = \frac{2}{(1-x^2)^2}
\end{cases}
$$(1-x^2)Q_1^{''}-2xQ_1^{'} + 2Q_1 = \frac{2}{1-x^2} - \left(xlog\frac{1+x}{1-x} + \frac{2x^2}{1-x^2}\right) + \left(xlog\frac{1+x}{1-x} - 2\right) = 0$$